Homotopy equivalence of the tetrahedron minus its interior
Let's consider a tetrahedron $T$. Let's remove the interior and the interior of three of its faces. What space is it homotopy equivalent to?
My attempt.
Suppose that the base of the tetrahedron is the only face that has interior. If we "smash" the top vertex of the tetrahedron to the base, we get a triangle with a point in the interior and three edges joining it to the vertices. After that I don't know what else to do. Another idea I came up with was to contract the triangle to a point, and we would get a wedge sum of circles. However, I don't know if this is right.

Contract the base triangle to a point. This gives you two vertices (the top vertex and what used to be the base) connected by three separate arcs. Contract one of the arcs, and you get the wedge of two circles.
